# How to select polygons by points in R?

Tags: r, overlay

I have a shapefile with polygons and another one with points. I would like to create a new shapefile with those polygons that don't contain any point inside. I tried the function `sp::over` in R and it returns a vector indicating which polygons have points, but I have been unable to create the new shapefile from there.

```
 library(sp) 
 polygons <-over(basins,points_proj)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of the over function returning a query, now you have to do something with it. One easy approach is to pass an is.na() evaluation to a bracket index of the the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object. This will return a subset of polygons that do not intersect the points.

First, create some example data.

```
require(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
sr1=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180114, 180553, 181127, 181477, 181294, 181007, 180409, 
  180162, 180114), c(332349, 332057, 332342, 333250, 333558, 333676, 
  332618, 332413, 332349)))),'1')
sr2=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180042, 180545, 180553, 180314, 179955, 179142, 179437, 
  179524, 179979, 180042), c(332373, 332026, 331426, 330889, 330683, 
  331133, 331623, 332152, 332357, 332373)))),'2')
sr3=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(179110, 179907, 180433, 180712, 180752, 180329, 179875, 
  179668, 179572, 179269, 178879, 178600, 178544, 179046, 179110),
  c(331086, 330620, 330494, 330265, 330075, 330233, 330336, 330004, 
  329783, 329665, 329720, 329933, 330478, 331062, 331086)))),'3')
sr4=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180304, 180403,179632,179420,180304),
  c(332791, 333204, 333635, 333058, 332791)))),'4')
sr=SpatialPolygons(list(sr1,sr2,sr3,sr4))
srdf=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sr, data.frame(row.names=c('1','2','3','4'), PIDS=1:4))

plot(srdf)
  plot(meuse, pch=20, add=TRUE)
```

Now, we can subset the polygons to ones not intersecting points.

```
polys.sub <- srdf[is.na(sp::over(srdf, sp::geometry(meuse))), ] 
plot(meuse, pch=20)
  plot(polys.sub, add=T)
```

By adding a "is not" evaluation (using !), you can invert the subset to include polygons that DO intersect the points.

```
polys.sub <- srdf[!is.na(sp::over(srdf, sp::geometry(meuse))), ] 
plot(meuse, pch=20)
  plot(polys.sub, add=T)
```